# JSP read React JSX

Tags: reactjs, jsp

i'm planning to add in react into my new page of jsp slowly for revamp.

i tried an example by add lib below in my **template.jsp**

```
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6/babel.min.js"></script>
```

**index.jsp**

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>

<div id="tab-1">
    <h1>GoodBye World</h1>
</div>

<div id="tab-2">
    <div id="react_container"></div>

    <script type="text/babel">
        function App(){
            return (
                <div id="container">
                    <h1>hello world</h1>
                </div>
            );
        }

        ReactDOM.render(
            <App/>, 
            document.getElementById('react_container')
        );
    </script>
</div>
```

Above is follow some success sample in html but when i move it to jsp then the page showing blank without any error or exception.

Any idea where i do it wrongly ? Or in JSP file are not supporting React-JSX at all?

Comment: Is this the entire .jsp file?

Comment: @Kraylog hi, consider yes, the rest is some basic html code...

Comment: Well, that _basic HTML code_ can be the cause of problems, especially if it contains  links to scripts or other resources (which should be handled differently in webapp than in a static HTML file/template).